# Is there an etymological relationship between "obvious" and "obviate"

Tags: etymology

It is obvious to me that the words are related, just by spelling. Yet, no dictionary I glanced though reveals the link. I guess that *obvious* is something that eliminates (obviates) the uncertainty. It is obvious. Is that right?

Comment: Try 'The Free Dictionary by Farlex' - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obvious and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obviate and you'll see the common root. It's not quite what you think.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obviate&allowed_in_frame=0) is one of ELU's general references. They are definitely related, and their evolution through slightly different meanings of the Latin prefix *ob-* might be in scope here.

Comment: Your "folk etymology" is mistaken. [*Obvious*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obvious) comes from Latin *[that which is] in the way, presenting itself readily, open, exposed, commonplace*. Nothing to do with eliminating anything. And [*obviate*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obviate) has essentially the same etymology, although the meanings have clearly diverged over millennia.

Comment: Now I see the etymology is `contradictions are conspicuous`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent example of two modern words that are farther away from each other than they seem:

The ancient history of [*obvious*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obvious&allowed_in_frame=0):

> 1580s, "frequently met with,"
>
> from Latin *obvius* "that is in the way, presenting itself readily,
>   open, exposed, commonplace,"
>
> from *obviam* (adv.) "in the way,"
>
> from *ob* "against" (see ob-) + *viam*, accusative of via "way"
>
> (see [via](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=via&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> [ablative form of *via* "way, road, path, highway, channel, course," from
>   PIE *wegh- "to go, convey"]
>
> Meaning "*plain to see, evident*" is first recorded 1630s.

The ancient history of [*obviate*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obviate&allowed_in_frame=0):

> 1590s, "to meet and do away with,"
>
> from Late Latin *obviatus*, past participle of *obviare* "act contrary to,
>   go against,"
>
> from Latin *obvius* "that is in the way, that moves against" (see
>   obvious)

Though both reach back to the Latin *obvius*, the primary difference seems to appear in the connection to the Latin singular accusative *[viam](https://books.google.com/books?id=j48UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA12-IA34&lpg=PA12-IA34&dq=Latin%20viam%20vs%20vius&source=bl&ots=uDbYtN1j5K&sig=Scn6f5qAxzYtQ77v3RtKaQZLyZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eYvbVJqMIcmpNrG5hKAK&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Latin%20viam%20vs%20vius&f=false)*

> Phr.: on the r[oad]., inter viam, Cic.

Though routinely defined as *against*, the Latin prefix [*ob*-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ob-&allowed_in_frame=0) could imply several meanings, depending on how it was used:

> prefix meaning "toward, against, across, down," also used as an
>   intensive,
>
> from Latin ob "toward, to, over against, in the way of, by reason of,
>   about, before, in front of,"
>
> from PIE root *epi, also *opi "near,
>   against" (see epi-).

With *viam*, *ob*- produces "in [front of] the way" and, by extension since 1630, "plain to see" in [obvious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obvious):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Easily perceived or understood; clear, self-evident, or apparent:

In *obviatus*, the *ob*- carries more of the *against* connotation with the more active past participle of *viare*, producing "move against," and eventually by 1590 "meet and do away with" in *[obviate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obviate)*:

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Remove (a need or difficulty):
>
> 1.1 Avoid or prevent (something undesirable):

www.etymonline.com

A Smaller English-Latin Dictionary: Abridged from the Larger Dictionary

www.oxforddictionaries.com

Comment: There’s something delightfully oxymoronic, yet perfectly logical really, about “the more active past [passive] participle”.

Comment: Yes, which is *more* active: a past participle in the passive voice or a noun? Passive past participle by a nose!

Comment: Depends on the pair, surely. I’d think of _slaughter_ or _rested_ (as nouns) as more active than _deceased_ or _slept_, for example, regardless of word classes. But this is a wholly different meaning of _active_ than the one I was quipping about. :-)

Comment: Supernal answer!